# Optimize laravel join query

Tags: laravel, optimization

Is there anyone who can optimize below query please. Mids table has records 166 and orders table has records 350000 (0.35 million). Query is taking more than one minute on local as well as in database. Please check below query code:

```
DB::table('mids')->join('orders', 'orders.gateway_id', '=', 'mids.gateway_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('mids.*', DB::raw('SUM(orders.order_total) as sum')))
        ->addSelect(DB::raw('sum(case when orders.order_status = "2" then 1 else 0 end) as mid_count'))
        ->addSelect(DB::raw('sum(case when orders.order_status = "7" then 1 else 0 end) as decline_per'))
        ->groupBy('mids.id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

hey brother instead of multiple `DB::raw and addselect()` you cam simply use it in this way:

```
DB::table('mids')->join('orders', 'orders.gateway_id', '=', 'mids.gateway_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('mids.*, SUM(orders.order_total) as sum,
        sum(case when orders.order_status = "2" then 1 else 0 end) as mid_count,
        sum(case when orders.order_status = "7" then 1 else 0 end) as decline_per'))
        ->groupBy('mids.id')->get();
```

But i suggest use pagination if you are fetching large data and for pagination docs will be more helpful: [Database: Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results)